# Dart Editor: Pub build produces dysfunctional files

Tags: javascript, deployment, build, dart, publish

I'm working on a dart thing. Everything works flawlessly when I test it in Dartium. But when I Pub Build the project and run the .html file in the build/web folder, everything that's dart gets completely ignored.

I thought the problem might be in my code, but this does not seem to be the case since I don't even need to write any. It's enough if I just create a new project from the 'Web application' template and keep the template code in there (you know, the one with a "Click me!" text that reverses if you click it).

I get no errors while building the project. I build the project by right-clicking on pubspec.yaml and choosing the 'Pub Build (generates JS)' - Is this the right way of doing it, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to open the developer console in your browser to check if there are any errors? `F12` in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Ah yes! There is the: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" concerning the dart.js file.
I indeed do not have the dart.js file in my project. It seems that it should be located in the packages/browser/, but it never got generated. There is only the interop.js file in that folder.

Comment: Are you talking about the `build/web? directory or the `web` directory? The `build/web` contains your build output. There shouldn't be a packages directory. 
What Dart version are you using?
Can you try to run `pub build` from the console from the application directory (the directory containing the pubspec.yaml) file. As far as I know from DartEditor it is run in debug mode by default and from the console in release mode by default. The debug result might reference the source directory and this might cause troubles.

Comment: I didn't know about the debug/release mode, good to know! Running it from console didn't solve the problem, but it was indeed caused by the missing dart.js file. A quick google search has revealed that there has been at least one other dude in the past with the same problem (https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/6QEYk45zPfA) and that, here's the funny part: it was you who has provided the solution to him and ultimately to me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it was caused by the missing dart.js in the "packages/browser"
Running the 'pub cache repair' command was sufficient in bringing the missing file back and now everything works.